# frames per seconds

Tags: python

I want to limit the calculation-speed. There was a command for rate per second. Could anybody help me? 
doesn't rate() work in the newer version of Python?
Thanks

Comment: Limit the calculation-speed of *what*? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: You might be thinking of the rate() function in Visual Python: http://vpython.org/ -- you could of course use it in applications that don't otherwise use the VPython library, but it would be a little silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ignacio said, you can measure the time since the last calculation, calculate the time until the next, and sleep until then. You can also do it without any other framework, for example, with these functions:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

t = datetime.now()[5] # milliseconds
dt = # do some calculation for time needed to sleep
time.sleep(dt) # sleep in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an event loop framework such as Twisted will allow you to schedule your next calculation in the future once you have completed the current calculation, and to sleep until that time.

Comment: do you know the rate()-function?

Answer (score 0):

i found it again. There is a rate()-function in the visual-module.
you can use it in the while-loop.